# Are 6loWPAN stacks in TinyOS and Contiki compatible?

Tags: testing, networking, continuous-integration, tinyos, contiki

As far as Google suggests, the 6loWPAN stack in Contiki and TinyOS should be compatible, though I could quite see any sort of reports on both being continuously tested in some fashion. Does anybody have more information on this? I had been mostly using Contiki, and thought considering to use TOS for one of my next projects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SICS group has published two papers on interoperability:.

1. [Beyond Interoperability – Pushing the Performance of Sensor Network IP Stacks](http://dunkels.com/adam/ko11beyond.pdf)
2. [ContikiRPL and TinyRPL: Happy Together](https://www.sics.se/~adam/ko11contikirpl.pdf)